# Number guesser using function and midpoint

Tags: c++

I am writing a program  for number guesser using function and midpoint to find out the number that been chosen. I have a problem compiling and I can't figure out the problem ????

The description of my problem:

> The `playOneGame` function should have a return type of void. It should
>   implement a complete guessing game on the range of 1 to 100.
>
> The `shouldPlayAgain` function should have a boolean return type. It
>   should prompt the user to determine if the user wants to play again,
>   read in a character, then return true if the character is a ‘y’, and
>   otherwise return false.
>
> In addition, you should implement the helper functions
>   `getUserResponseToGuess`, and `getMidpoint`. They should be invoked inside
>   your `playOneGame` function.
>
> `getUserResponseToGuess`. This function should prompt the user with the
>   phrase “is it ? (h/l/c): “  with the value replacing the token
>   . It should return a char. The char should be one of three
>   possible values: ‘h’, ‘l’, or ‘c’.  It should have the following
>   signature: `char getUserResponseToGuess(int guess)`
>
> `getMidpoint`. This function should accept two integers, and it should
>   return the midpoint of the two integers. If there are two values in
>   the middle of the range then you should consistently chose the smaller
>   of the two. It should have the following signature: `int getMidpoint(int low, int high)`

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void playOneGame;
char getUserResponseToGuess(int guess);
int getMidpoint ( int low, int high);

int main() {
    do
    {
        playOneGame();
    } while (shouldPlayAgain());
    return 0;
}

void playOneGame
{
    int a = 100;
    cout << "\nGuess a number between 1 and 100. " <<endl;
    getUserResponseToGuess ( a);
}


char getUserResponseToGuess(int guess)
{
    while (true)
    {
        int guess = getMidpoint(minimum, maximum);
        std::cout << "\nIs it [h]igher/[l]ower/[e]qual to " << guess << "? ";
        char answer;
        if (!(std::cin >> answer))
        {
            std::cerr << "error reading user input, program exiting\n";
            exit(1);
        }
        if (answer == 'h')
            minimum = guess + 1;
        else if (answer == 'l')
            maximum = guess - 1;
        else if (answer == 'e')
        {
            std::cout << "Well, isn't that nice.\n";
            return;
        }
        if (minimum > maximum)
        {
            std::cerr << "hey, you lied to me!\n";
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

int getMidpoint ( int low, int high)
{

    int mid;

    mid = (low + high) / 2;

    return mid;

}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly in order to make it readable.

Answer (score 1):

`void playOneGame;` is not a function forward declaration. `void playOneGame();` is. Also the same applies for the function definition.

Also, you should define `shouldPlayAgain()` and include `<stdlib.h>` for `exit()` to work.

And `getUserResponseToGuess()` has just a `return` instead of returning something useful and it does not return anything on the default branch.